# List elements not being updated?

Tags: python

In this program I am trying to make it so that, given a list of elements of the character 'P' from indices 0 to n + 1 (n being a user inputted value), if the index of an element is a non-prime number, then the element would update itself from 'P' to 'NP'. In my code, I made a for loop that will increment through the list elements and for each element it would put the index of that element through another for loop where it will turn all the elements with indices that are **multiples** of the original index to 'NP'.

For some reason however, when I enter the value 10 to create a list of 11 elements (with indices ranging from 0-10) it returns this list: ['NP', 'NP', 'P', 'NP', 'NP', 'NP', 'NP', 'NP', 'NP', 'NP', 'NP'] I was wondering why it is turning all of the elements after the element at index 2 to 'NP'?

````
listOfNum = []
count = 2
divCheck = 1

while True:
    userNum = int(input("Enter number of elements greater than or equal to 10: "))
    if userNum < 10:
        print("Invalid input, input must be higher than or equal to 10")
    elif userNum >= 10:
        listOfNum = ['P'] * (userNum + 1)
        listOfNum[0] = "NP"
        listOfNum[1] = "NP"
        for i in range(2, userNum+1):
            if listOfNum[i] == "NP":
                continue
            elif listOfNum[i] == "P":
                for z in range(i+1, userNum+1):
                    if ((listOfNum.index(listOfNum[z]) % listOfNum.index(listOfNum[i])) != 0):
                        continue 
                    elif (listOfNum.index(listOfNum[z]) % listOfNum.index(listOfNum[i])) == 0:
                        listOfNum[z] = "NP"
            print(listOfNum)
            break  ```
````

Comment: argh `listOfNum.index(listOfNum[i]))` returns the first occurrence. Just use `z` in your case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listOfNum.index(listOfNum[z])` is a big no no as it looks for the value of the element linearly from the start of the list, so it returns the *first* element.

replace by `z` which is the index that you defined in the `range` loop.

```
if ((listOfNum.index(listOfNum[z]) % listOfNum.index(listOfNum[i])) != 0):
```

becomes

```
if z % i:
```

not sure if there are other problems but it should work better.

here's a much simpler rewrite of the `z` loop:

```
for z in range(i+1, userNum+1):
     if z % i == 0:
        listOfNum[z] = "NP"
```

Comment: Wow I think I overthought it too much thank you so much!